# How do I pass the data from one React.js file to another?

Tags: html, json, reactjs, dom, local-storage

I'd like to pass data from `App.js` to another `.js` file within React. Atm, I'm reading and writing from local storage between files but this seems inefficient. I'd like to only pull from local storage once when the `App.js` component mounts. This is what I'm doing currently.

**App.js:**

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: {},
      user_data: (localStorage.getItem('user_data')),
    }
    this.authListener = this.authListener.bind(this);
  }  
 componentDidMount() {
    this.authListener();

  }

//checks firebase for authentication
  authListener() {
    Authentication.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      console.log(user);
      if (user) {
        this.setState({ user });
        localStorage.setItem('user', user.uid);
        this.pulldata_Health();
        this.pulldata_Meals();
        this.pulldata_Ingredients();
      } else {
        this.setState({ user: null })
        localStorage.removeItem('user');
        localStorage.removeItem('user_data')
      }
    });
  }

  //connects to database and stores data to local storage
  pulldata_Health() {
    database.collection('Health_data')
      .doc(localStorage.getItem('user'))
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        const data = doc.data();
        localStorage.setItem('user_data', JSON.stringify(data));
        console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user_data')))
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error("Error reading health", error);
      });
```

**Homepage.js:**

```
     constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                healthData: (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user_data')))
            }
        }
  componentDidMount() {
        this.GoalChecker();
        console.log(this.state.healthData);
    }

    GoalChecker() {
        if (this.state.healthData !== null) {

            if (this.state.healthData.goal === 'Gain') {
                this.setState({ gainImage: true });
                this.setState({ recompImage: false });
                this.setState({ loseImage: false });
                console.log('gainimg')
            }

            if (this.state.healthData.goal === 'Recomp') {
                this.setState({ gainImage: false });
                this.setState({ recompImage: true });
                this.setState({ loseImage: false });
                console.log('recompimg')
            }

            if (this.state.healthData.goal === 'Lose') {
                this.setState({ gainImage: false });
                this.setState({ recompImage: false });
                this.setState({ loseImage: true });
                console.log('loseimg')
            }
        }
    };
```

This all works, but pulling from local storage every time this page loads seems a bit inefficient. Is there any way to push the props of User data from `App.js` to my other page?

Comment: Use a global state or look into `redux`

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult for me to explain, but i'll show you a video from YouTube how to do this with react-hooks. It is not a very difficult method
 https://youtu.be/XuFDcZABiDQ

Comment: Hi i've been looking through and I'm not sure how I can update the set state when app.js component did mount as that's what I want to do? I understand how I'd do it with a separate component but not that?

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use react context.  Create a context within app.js/at the top of your application.  Wrap the top-level container using a context component. Within any child components, you can then access props in the global context.

A great tutorial that explains it is here, https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively